# SQL table doesn't exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a problem with ADO.NET query. I Create Database successfuly. There is only one table (`RegUsers`) in this database (I am just testing the work with ADO.NET). EDIT: Databese is based on Microsoft Azure

Create of a my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RegUsers] (
[Id]       INT          NOT NULL,
[Login]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Password]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Name]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Surname] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

I create `SqlConnecion` and successfully connect to the database (I hope that successfully if I can Open the connection) and then I'd like to `INSERT` data into this table with this:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder csBuilder;
csBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csBuilder.DataSource = "********.database.windows.net";
csBuilder.Encrypt = true;
csBuilder.TrustServerCertificate = false;
csBuilder.UserID = "************".ToString();
csBuilder.Password = "********".ToString();
csBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30


SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(csBuilder.ToString());

con.Open();

string PlneniDaty =
@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegUsers] (Login,Password,Name,Surname)"+
@" VALUES ('MyLogin','MyPassword','Pavel','Novak')";

SqlCommand NaplDaty = new SqlCommand(PlneniDaty, con);
NaplDaty.ExecuteNonQuery();   

con.Close();
```

Whenever I execute this command It display Error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.RegUsers'

(and yes the table was successfully created I can see it in SQL Server object Explorer)

Where is the problem?

Comment: Test with `[YourDBName].[dbo].[RegUsers]` if it works you are not specifying the correct DB name in the connection string, if it does not work ensure the schema name is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're executing a insert query in a database dbo.RegUsers and it's giving the error Invalid object name 'dbo.RegUsers'? That simply means that table cannot find an object called "RegUsers ". There are several possible reasons for this:

The object doesn't exist, possibly because the schema and/or database don't exist
The object exists, but the database is case-sensitive and some part of the name doesn't match the name in your code

You'll need to investigate more to find out what the cause is in your case, but as a complete guess, your production server has both the RegUsers and databases?

Finally, when posting questions please always include your SQL Server version (2000/2005/2008) and edition (Express, Standard, Enterprise); they can be very important when talking about schemas and permissions, because features and behaviour can be different.

Comment: Sorry for missing information ... It is even worse... I use database which is base on Windows Azure. The name is correct (I coppied it for sure). And finaly Database is realy exists (I look it again) and table in it too.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I Edit it in main article ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your entire code looks good.you can post your connectionString.
Following things you need to check.

1. Connection String ( Data Source Name , Database Name )
2. Schema of your table.

Comment: SqlConnectionStringBuilder csBuilder;
    csBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    csBuilder.DataSource = "********.database.windows.net";
    csBuilder.Encrypt = true;
    csBuilder.TrustServerCertificate = false;
    csBuilder.UserID = "************".ToString();
    csBuilder.Password = "********".ToString();
    csBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;

Comment: Please try using this connection string. Replace @DataSource with your server Name,@DatabaseName with your database Name. and your username and password.

Data Source=@DataSource;Initial Catalog=@DatabaseName;Integrated Security=true;User Id=@userid; Password=@password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Id like to switch DataSource for DatabaName but object SqlConnectionStringBuilder doesn't know method DatabaseName and same is for ProviderName

Comment: Problem solved ... all It's need was add "InitialCatalog" method to the ConnectionString ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your create script, your table's name is RegUzivatele, while you're trying to insert to a table name RegUsers, which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I am Czech and for better understand I translate my czech nemas to english and I forgot to overwrite this name. In my databese is correct.